# C++ - unordered_map operator [], unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, loops, unordered-map

This is a simple script I was working on, but I failed to understand why it was behaving unexpectedly.

Basically, I had an array of integers with duplicates, and I wanted to store the number of times an element occurred in the array along with the element's value in an unordered_map,

Then, for each entry in the map {*k*, *v*}, I needed to determine if *k + 1* existed in the array, and if so, do something with it. 
Below you can see the code.

```
vector<int> A = {1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3};

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) m[A[i]]++;

int ans = 0;

for (const auto& e: m) {
    if (m[e.first + 1] > 0) ans = max(ans, e.second + m[e.first + 1]);
}
```

Everything seemed to work. However, when *k + 1* did not exist in the unordered_map, the loop would just terminate, and I do not understand why.

According to c++ documentation, the operator [] inserts a new element if it does not exist . But that does not tell me anything about the loop just not working.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I am modifying the unordered_map inside the loop. If this is the case, could you guys elaborate more on that?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `m[e.first + 1]` inside your loop will insert a new element into `m` if it does not exist, which will cause problems for the loop itself because a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses iterators internally, and altering a `std::unordered_map` while you are iterating through it with iterators is **undefined behavior**, as [an insertion *may* invalidate the iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at):

> **If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated**. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not invalidated. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.

To avoid that, use the map's [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method instead to check for a key's existence without inserting it:

```
for (const auto& e: m) {
    auto iter = m.find(e.first + 1);
    if (iter != m.end()) ans = max(ans, e.second + iter->second);
}
```